# Using counts in a 2-by-2 table to get probabilities and conditional probabilities

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Among the 30 applicants for a position at a bank, some are married and some are not, some have had experience in banking and some have not, with the exact breakdown being:

```
                     Married      Single 
Some experience      6             3 
No experience        12            9
```

If the branch manager randomly chooses the applicant to be interviewed first, in which M denotes the event that the applicant is married, and E denotes that the applicant has had some experience in banking, find the value of $P(M)$, $P(M \cap E)$ and $P(E|M)$.

I answered it like this, but not really sure if it is correct:

$P(M) = 18/30 = 0.6$

$P(M \cap E) = 6/30 = 0.2$

$P(E|M) = P(E \cap M)/ P(M) = 0.2/0.6 = 0.33$

Comment: Nicely done. You got them all!

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://www.onemathematicalcat.org/MathJaxDocumentation/TeXSyntax.htm) to format your posts.  To begin with, surround math expressions (including numbers) with `$` signs and use `_` for subscripts.  `$x_1$` comes out as $x_1$.

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: Just a note on making your MathJax pretty: If you would like to insert the mathematical symbol for intersection in a formula, \cap gives $\cap$.

Comment: Edited your Q to show use of $\cap$ made by using `\cap` inside math-mode `$`'s. Also to make topic-specific title. // All correct (+1). // For the last part, you might restrict attention only to the 18 subjects in the first column $(M)$ and then say $P(E|M) = 6/18$ directly.